# Проверить наличие определённых данных в MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Я делаю бота на Python с библиотекой python-telegram-bot и базой данных MySQL.

Мой бот создан для записи на приём к мастеру, все данные пользователей (name, user_id, phone, data, time) сохраняются в базе данных MySQL. Нужно чтобы бот проверял есть ли запись на этот день и время, и если есть, появлялось всплывающее окно "Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!".
Предполагаю это нужно сделать через SELECT:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT data, time FROM users")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Но как быть дальше? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Пробовала вот так, но ничего не происходит:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT data, time FROM users")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
if myresult:
    query.answer_callback_query(text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
    print('Найдено в бд')
else:
    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
    print('Не найдено в бд')
```

**Пример таблицы users:**

```
+----+-----------+---------+-------+------------+-------+
| id | user_name | user_id | phone |    data    |  time |
+----------------+---------+-------+------------+-------+
| 1  | Marco     |  586512 | 98422 | 22/09/2020 | 12:00 |
| 2  | Oksi      |  548816 | 32145 | 19/09/2020 | 14:30 |
| 3  | Jack      |  866321 | 96374 | 09/09/2020 | 12:00 |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+------+
```

Нужно проверить в бд есть ли уже какой-то пользователь, к примеру, на 22/09/2020 на 12:00.
Если есть, в боте появляется всплывающее окно "Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!".
Если нету, бот переходит к следующему шагу и просит ввести имя.

Вот часть кода, где пользователь выбирает дату и время. И я думаю, что после нажатия inline кнопки (callback_data='12') в функции `on_time_12` нужно сделать проверку на наличие выбранного времени и даты в базе данных. Чтобы не было регистрации на одно и тоже время в тот же день.

```
@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_select_date(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global text_data
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    bot = context.bot

    selected, date = telegramcalendar.process_calendar_selection(bot, update)
    if not selected:
        return ConversationHandler.END

    user_data = context.user_data
    text_data = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    user_data['Дата'] = text_data

    keyboard = [[
        InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("14:30", callback_data='14'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("16:00", callback_data='16')
    ]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    query.message.reply_text(text='''Вы выбрали %s
Выберите свободное время: ''' % text_data, reply_markup=reply_markup)

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global text_time
    user_data = context.user_data
    text_time = '12:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text_time

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Comment: Я не пойму, что надо. Я думал вы хотите проверить есть ли что-нибудь по запросу `SELECT data, time FROM users`. Если вы хотите запросы есть ли в таблице какая-то запись, то опишите таблицу пожалуйста ;)

Comment: Ваш пример ничего не показывает, в `myresult` вы получаете все записи "дата, время",но вы их никак не проверяете, ни с чем не сравниваете

Comment: Вот я не знаю как его проверить и с чем сравнить. Дополнила вопрос частью кода. Надеюсь теперь более понятно, что я хочу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяйте теперь примерно так:

```
def check(date: str, time: str):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE data=date AND time=time")
    return myresult = mycursor.fetchone()


@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global text_time
    user_data = context.user_data
    text_time = '12:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text_time

    if check(user_data['Дата'], user_data['Время']):
        query.answer_callback_query(text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
        print('Найдено в бд')
    else:
        query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if myresult:
    print('yeah there are some data ;)')
else:
    print('sorry, nothing (')
```